# Hegazy-Green Test For Normality

Tags: r, statistics

What is the difference between `hegazy1.norm.test` and `hegazy2.norm.test`? Which of the two will provide better analysis of the data? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: The difference seems to be in $T_2$ one has absolute value and other is squared, thus $T_2$ will differ but the result of the test should be the same.

Comment: @jyr. I used both tests for the same datasets, yet hegazy1.norm.test and hegazy2.norm.test provide different values for p.

Comment: Because  p-value is computed by Monte Carlo simulation it is possible there is small difference, did it change the result of the analysis?